# Why am I getting this error "local variable 'text' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a share function using python and Django and when I run "share" it gives me back an error. Here's my code:

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from basicapp.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm, PostForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basicapp.models import UserProfileInfo


from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
@login_required
def user_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        form = PostForm()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        HttpResponse("Not Valid try dat boi agian")

    render(request, 'basicapp/userpost.html', 
                    {'form':form,
                     'text':text})
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    post = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
```

[This is the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urug2.png)

Comment: Please paste the text of your error mesaage, not an image.

Comment: Avoid external links and images but show the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: If `form.is_valid()` is False then  your variable `text` is not assigned but your dictionary tries to refer to it. That's the reason of the error I believe.

Comment: What don’t you understand, exactly?

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the `HttpResponse` in your `else` block execution continues to next line of code which wants a `text` variable to be defined, but since the `is_valid` block never ran, there is no `text` in scope.

You will also never get to the final line once you have a `return` in both the `if` and `else` branches of the `form.is_valid()` test.

```
def user_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        form = PostForm()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not Valid try dat boi agian") # return here

    return render(request, 'basicapp/userpost.html', # should return here too but this line will never run
                           {'form':form,
                            'text':text})
```

Comment: Can you please clarify.